Toilet flush button not activating flush
My toilet flush recently stopped activating the flush. I opened up the tank and noticed a setup that I'm not too used to, and don't really know how to fix yet.
The lid of the tank ends up just pressing either the blue or white button and the flush generally activates. Pressing the button right now doesn't do anything.
I was wondering if there are any simple things to check before I call a plumber. The other flush in a different bathroom works so I don't believe its a general water issue.


how come you have no water in the tank

I thought the water in the tank gets filled up, when I flush and it re-fills it up with water? The last flush worked, but I think it didnt fill it back in with water?

then you do not have a problem with flushing ... you have a problem with filling ... please update your question with a description of the actual problem

^ Sorry, I meant the flush doesn't work right now either (along with filling). When I press the flush buttons (blue or white), the water from the pot doesn't drain eithr. By my last comment I meant I assume that since the last time the flush worked, the flush+fill function has not worked properly.

Does it start filling if you pull the float up?

First, look at pulling the assembly out and soaking it in vinegar for a few hours. This might dissolve the mineral deposits that seem to have accumulated. That may be what's got it gummed up.
If that doesn't help, replace the valve assembly. It's probably just worn out. It'll almost certainly be much less expensive than a plumber visit. This is very much a DIY project for a motivated individual and is probably available at your local store or online.

Thanks for the quick reply! Do you have any pointers on what to start disassembling? I see the one area that looks like I could take a screwdriver to. Is that the main area to begin and then slowly take it completely apart, and then submerge just in vinegar ?

I don't know your particular hardware. They tend to be removable as a unit, though. so I'd start there. Whether you take it apart depends on what you see for screws, etc.

I tried soaking in vinegar yet it seems to have had no effect unfortunately.

Due to some serious deposits your fill valve is stuck in close position.
Gently push down the arm with the screw at the end, that should activate the filling.
Needles to say you have to clean the tank and all in it using some vinegar..
Usually replacing the fill valve is a DIY job, but if you do not feel comfortable get a handyman, no need for plumber.
